# Adding hero-unit in the middle of the page

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/66501

I want to put hero-unit box in the middle of the page (vertically).  I set the size(span10) for the box.  Also, there is a problem that the text from the bar is a little bit off and I don't know the reason.  Please help me out!

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide fullscrn">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active fullscrn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x480" class="fullscrn">
        </div>
        <div class="item fullscrn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x480" class="fullscrn">
        </div>
        <div class="item fullscrn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x480" class="fullscrn">
        </div>
    </div> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
 <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>

<div class="hero-unit span10">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>
    </p><div class="progress progress-striped active">
      <div class="bar" style="width: 11%;">11%</div>
    </div>
  <p></p>
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
    Learn more
  </a>
</p>
</div>

for CSS: 
.fullscrn{
height: 100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your solution

```
<div id="full-screen-slider" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active fullscrn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x480" class="fullscrn">
        </div>
        <div class="item fullscrn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x480" class="fullscrn">
        </div>
        <div class="item fullscrn">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x480" class="fullscrn">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a> <a class="carousel-control right"
        href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
<style>
    #full-screen-slider
    {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .carousel .carousel-inner .item img
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .all-sliders
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 25px;
        right: 25px;
        color: white;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .all-sliders:hover
    {
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<div style="top: 21%; left: 16%; position: absolute;" class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="hero-unit span10 ">
            <h1>
                Test</h1>
            <p>
            </p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="bar" style="width: 11%;">
                    11%</div>
            </div>
            <p>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function setFullScreen() {
            browserHeight = $(window).height();
            $("#full-screen-slider .carousel-inner .item img").css({
                height: browserHeight - 20
            });
        }
        $("#full-screen-slider .carousel-inner .item:eq(0)").addClass('active');
        setFullScreen();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            setFullScreen();
        });
        $("#full-screen-slider").carousel({ interval: 5000 });
        if ($('.content').length > 0) {
            $('.content').css('height', ($(window).height() - $('.content-section').offset().top - 120));
        }




    });

</script>
```